# WPF Get Element(s) under mouse

Tags: wpf, element, visualtreehelper, visual-tree

Is there a way with WPF to get an array of elements under the mouse on a MouseMove event?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From "[WPF Unleashed](https://web.archive.org/web/20081205070201/http://adamnathan.net/wpf/)", page 383:

> Visual hit testing can inform you
> about *all* `Visual`s that intersect a
> location, [...] you must use [...] the
> `[VisualTreeHelper.]HitTest` method that accepts a
> `HitTestResultCallback` delegate. Before
> this version of `HitTest` returns, the
> delegate is invoked once for each
> relevant `Visual`, starting from the
> topmost and ending at the bottommost.

The signature of such a callback is

```
HitTestResultBehavior Callback(HitTestResult result)
```

and it has to return `HitTestResultBehaviour.Continue` to receive further hits, as shown below (from the linked page on MSDN):

```
// Return the result of the hit test to the callback.
public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
{
    // Add the hit test result to the list that will be processed after the enumeration.
    hitResultsList.Add(result.VisualHit);

    // Set the behavior to return visuals at all z-order levels.
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
```

For further information, please consult the [MSDN documentation for `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: See the following msdn link (section: Using a Hit Test Result Callback) for a good example. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx)

Comment: Note that you get a visual tree element which most of the time is not what you need. You have to search up through the parents of the hits recursively to get your logical view elements.

Answer (score 47):

You can also try using the Mouse.DirectlyOver property to get the top-most element that is under the mouse.

Comment: This will **not** provide an array of elements under the mouse, though, but indeed only return the topmost element.

Comment: for me this returns null when used in a ListControl. weird.

Comment: one note - doesn't work with `Mouse.Capture(...)` and `Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent` : `If an element has mouse capture, the mouse pointer is considered directly over the element regardless of the where the mouse pointer is.`

Comment: `Mouse.Capture(...)` and `Mouse.DirectlyOver` related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399357/how-can-i-get-the-element-at-the-mouse-position-even-when-the-mouse-is-captured?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

Can you use the [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest.aspx) ?

http://lukieb.blogspot.com/2008/07/visualtreehelperhittest.html

Comment: The overload used in the linked example ([which should probably be replicated directly in the answer, as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)) will only find the topmost element at the mouse location, though, **not** an array of elements under the mouse.