# Checking which control was clicked basing on position of pointer

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8

I have got user control which have a popup (it is bigger than user control) Now I want to hide popup when user clicks in another part of a screen. (standard combobox behavior) How I can do this? I have tried to listen event pointer_click and I could get coordinates but it would be hard to manually check if user clicked on popup (maybe is there a way to check what control is on that coordinates?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813/wpf-get-elements-under-mouse) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this a WinRT app then simply

```
var popup = new Popup();
popup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
```

If normal xaml then why not dismiss as soon as you lose focus?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few possibilities:
-Use the VisualTree.Hittest method to get all controls of that point: if the result does not contain the popup hide it
-If you have sender object (or a RoutedEventArgs object) you can use the VisualTree to lookup for the popup. (rekursiv) if you dont find it -> hide it