# C# WPF Want the child of the Stackpanel on click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, stackpanel

I am using StackPanels. In my application I have to show a multi tiff with 3 to x images and have to open them in a new window after I click on one of them.

Showing them is easy:

```
public void Bilder_anzeigen(string path)
{
    TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(new Uri(path), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

    foreach (var i in decoder.Frames)
    {
        Image myImage = new Image();
        myImage.Source = i;
        Stackpanel_Tiff.Children.Add(myImage);
    }
}
```

But how can I get a child with a click on the StackPanel?  There is a MouseDown Event, but after it is raised, I don't know on which image i clicked. I just know there was a click.  How can I find the image that was clicked?

Comment: Did you try using PreviewMouseDown event?

Comment: Nope, can you maybe give me a hint what to do with this event? ;D

Comment: MouseDown and PreviewMouse down event work the same but have bubbling and tunneling behaviors. You can use PreviewMouseDown in the same way as you used MouseDown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out which `Image` was clicked on very easily using the `PreviewMouseDown` event and the `OriginalSource` of the `MouoseButtonEventArgs` object:

```
<StackPanel PreviewMouseDown="StackPanel_PreviewMouseDown">
    <Image Source="Images/Add_16.png" Stretch="None" />
    <Image Source="Images/Edit_16.png" Stretch="None" />
    <Image Source="Images/Copy_16.png" Stretch="None" />
</StackPanel>
```

...

```
private void StackPanel_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Image)
    {
        string imageSource = ((Image)e.OriginalSource).Source.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try OriginalSource of eventargs. OriginalSource give the control on which MouseDown

```
       private void Sp_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var image=e.OriginalSource as Image;
    }
```

Comment: And then pass `image` into your new Window.

Answer (score 3):

In your StackPanel's MouseDown Event, you can try;

```
if (e.OriginalSource is Image)
{
    var tapImage = (Image)e.OriginalSource;
    //tapImage is the Image on which user tapped.
}
```

see if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `Image.MouseDown` or `Image.MouseUp` event.

Alternatively, [get control under mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813/wpf-get-elements-under-mouse).

Comment: Mhm ..
Okay, but how can i use this on images created at runtime?
But i guess thats what im searching for :)

Comment: @user3793935 `myImage.MouseDown += ClickHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

while this works.

```
 image.MouseDown += (e, v) => { //enter your code };
```

I would still recommend you to use MVVM and bind the command through CommandBinding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx