# Attribute values of an element obtained where the cursor is located

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to get the attribute values of an element, where the cursor is located like `Tag`, `MouseLeftButtonDown` or `x:Name` and so on. The `Event` is always raised, when <kbd>F10</kbd> is pressed using CommandBindings:

XAML:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="Executesd"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F10" Command="Open"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Code:

```
private void Executesd(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Point mo = Mouse.GetPosition(Window);
    var TagName = Mouse.DirectlyOver;
    MessageBox.Show("Mouselogic Open-Commands: " + mo.ToString() + " -> " + TagName);
}
```

With `DirectlyOver` I only can get the `Control.Element`. Thats not exactly what I am looking for.

```
<TextBlock MouseLeftButtonDown="MaximizeToolbar" Tag="FolderNameOrWhatever">Test</TextBlock>
```

I'm not using Windows.Forms. With `Tag="FolderNameOrWhatever"` I want to handle an action. I also need the parents `Tag`, when there is no `Tag` in the child located.

I ve found nothing with google that fits my problem, getting the elements attributsname an values where my cursor is located.

May someone can help? I'm new at C#. In JS I could solve it, but C# is very different.

Comment: Have you looked at `VisualTreeHelper`?  That's what you would use to crawl up the visual tree to get the parent control.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did. I thought there is another short way to do it. 
But I still don't know which command to use to get the cursors located element attribute. Thats my main problem. :(

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813/wpf-get-elements-under-mouse

Comment: It's the same Result as with Mouse.DirectlyOver. I have read them all. :( The solution is to "convert" the Result it to a FrameworkElement. Took me many hours to find out how to solve. See answer below.

Thanks for replying Berin and trying to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
private void Executesd(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Point mo = Mouse.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

     FrameworkElement Happy = Mouse.DirectlyOver as FrameworkElement;
     MessageBox.Show("Mouselogic: " + mo.ToString() + " -> " + Happy.Tag);
}
```

Another way to do with VisualTreeHelper is like this (not full code):

```
.....
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this); i++)
{
    Visual VisualChild = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i);

    FrameworkElement Child = VisualChild as FrameworkElement;

    MessageBox.Show("Tag " + i + ": "+ Child.Tag +", Name: "+ Child.Name);
}
.....
```