# get name of element under mouse cursor on mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseclick-event, objectname

I am trying to make a method where i can get the element that was clicked. In App.xaml.cs i have method OnPreviewMouseDown that is activated for each click in application.

Now i need some help with getting element name from sender (if this is even possible)

```
 static void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;   // Sender gives you which control is clicked.
            string name = control.Name.ToString();  //returns main window name, not element....

            string typee = sender.GetType().ToString();  //returns PPPMain.Views.MainWindow

        }
    }
```

I tried this and some other suggestions from internet but didn't find any solutions...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `PreviewMouseDown` starts at the window and works its way down. `MouseDown` starts at the control and works it's way up. This is called "tunneling" and "bubbling", respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Get Element(s) under mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813/wpf-get-elements-under-mouse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `OriginalSource` property of the MouseButtonEventArgs:

```
var element = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
var name = element?.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this code inside your event:

```
VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, e.GetPosition(this));
```

you can find more in this other topic: [WPF Get Element(s) under mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813/wpf-get-elements-under-mouse)