# WPF MouseDown on Datagrid => Get Column and Row

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid

how can I recognize where I click on `DataGrid`?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" MouseDown="CellClick">

private void CellClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in TheGrid.SelectedCells)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(TheGrid.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item).ToString());
    }
}
```

many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand how?

Comment: I edit my Question. But this only work on >MouseUP< on MouseDown I get the "last" Cell... That's not the clean solution I'd like. is it possible to have a trigger that passes the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `SelectedCellsChanged` event like this:

```
private void TheGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TheGrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGridCellInfo dgci = TheGrid.SelectedCells[0];
        int columnIndex = dgci.Column.DisplayIndex;
        DataGridRow row = TheGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dgci.Item) as DataGridRow;
        int rowIndex = row.GetIndex();

        MessageBox.Show($"Row {rowIndex} Column {columnIndex}");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cell will get selected on MouseUp. To get the cell before this event occurred, you will have to listen on MouseDown on the Datagrid and check which element is under the mouse with [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182363/4244096) answer.